# ajax form is not working how it should

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

hello i been working on a form using ajax but when it comes down to validating a select box

problem 1) every time i leave the job_est value empty the form is still submitted as if it was validated

problem 2) can i use async in ajax
sorry for my writing skills

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

//if submit button is clicked
$('#submit').click(function () {        

    //Get the data from all the fields
    var name = $('input[name=name]');
            var l_name = $('input[name=l_name]');
            var phone = $('input[name=phone]');
    var email = $('input[name=email]');
            var postcode = $('input[name=postcode]');
            var house_number = $('input[name=house_number]');
            var street = $('input[name=street]');
            var job_est = $('select[name=job_est]');
    var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]');

    //Simple validation to make sure user entered something
    //If error found, add hightlight class to the text field
    if (name.val()=='') {
        name.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else name.removeClass('hightlight');
    if (l_name.val()=='') {
        l_name.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else l_name.removeClass('hightlight');
            if (phone.val()=='') {
        phone.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else phone.removeClass('hightlight');
    if (email.val()=='') {
        email.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else email.removeClass('hightlight');
            if (postcode.val()=='') {
        postcode.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else postcode.removeClass('hightlight');
            if (house_number.val()=='') {
        house_number.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else house_number.removeClass('hightlight');
            if (street.val()=='') {
        street.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else street.removeClass('hightlight');
            if (job_est.val()=='') {
        job_est.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else job_est.removeClass('hightlight');
    if (comment.val()=='') {
        comment.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else comment.removeClass('hightlight');

    //organize the data properly
    var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&phone=' + 
    phone.val() + '&comment='  + encodeURIComponent(comment.val());

    //disabled all the text fields
    $('.text').attr('disabled','true');

    //show the loading sign
    $('.loading').show();

    //start the ajax
    $.ajax({
        //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
        url: "process.php", 

        //GET method is used
        type: "GET",

        //pass the data         
        data: data,     

        //Do not cache the page
        cache: false,

        //success
        success: function (html) {              
            //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
            if (html==1) {                  
                //hide the form
                $('.form').fadeOut('slow');                 

                //show the success message
                $('.done').fadeIn('slow');

            //if process.php returned 0/false (send mail failed)
            } else alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');               
        }       
    });

    //cancel the submit button default behaviours
    return false;
    }); 
}); 
</script>

<body>


<div class="block">
<div class="done">
<b>Thank you !</b> We have received your message. 
</div>
<div class="form">
<form method="post" action="process.php">
<h4><u>Basic Contact Details</u></h4>
<div style="display: inline-block;" class="element">
    <label>Name</label><input type="text" name="name"/>
</div>
   <div style="display: inline-block;" class="element">
   <label>Last Name: </label><input type="text" name="l_name"/>
   </div>
   <div class="element">
    <label>Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone"/>
    </div>
<div class="element">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" class="element">
  <label>Postcode: </label><input type="text" name="postcode" size="10" maxlength="10">
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" class="element">
<label>House Number: </label><input type="text" name="house_number" size="3">
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" class="element">
  <label>Street Name: </label><input type="text" name="street">
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" class="element">
  <label>County:</label>
    <select>
      <option name="select">--SELECT--</option>
      <option name="bedford">Bedford</option>
      <option name="dunstable">Dunstable</option>
      <option name="luton">Luton</option>
    </select>
</div>

<h4><u>Job Details</u></h4>
<div class="element">
<label>You Would Like To Book A:</label>
<select name="job_est">
  <option name="select">--SELECT--</options>
  <option name="job">Job</option>
  <option name="est">Estimation</option>
</select>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="element">
<label>Service Your Booking:</label>
<select>
  <option name="select">--SELECT--</option>
  <option name="gardening">Gardening</option>
  <option name="landscaping">Landscaping</option>
  <option name="painting">Painting & Decorating</option>
  <option name="decking">Decking & Fencing</option>
</select>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="element">
    <label>Any Additional Information </label>
    <textarea name="comment" class="text textarea" /></textarea>
</div>
<div class="element">

    <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
    <div class="loading"></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: can you please trim down the code to just the parts relevant to the question

Comment: Formatting would also help

Comment: A fiddle would be lovely

Comment: Answer for #2: (A)synchronous(JAX).

Comment: You have to get the selected `option` from the select box. You are selecting the select element. Use `$('select[name=job_est]').find(":selected").text();//or .val()` instead of `$('select[name=job_est]');`

Comment: Your ajax function is in same file where html exists ?

Comment: @PalinDrome555 so replace $('select[name=job_est]') with find(":selected").text();

Comment: Depending on what you want, the `value` attribute on the `option` tag use `.val()`. Or the text between the tags use `.text()`. Then just check for `if(typeof job_est==='undefined' || job_est===''){//...}`.

Comment: i know ajax is asynchronous but when i try using the asynchronous on <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> this is where i get my library from the form stops using ajax and pass it to the next part of the form which sends the email and insert to my database and @tbi yes it in same file as html is that wrong to do it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change selectbox's `name` attribute with `value`

```
<select name="job_est">
  <option value="select">--SELECT--</options>
  <option value="job">Job</option>
  <option value="est">Estimation</option>
</select>
```

and in your javascript, it should be

```
if (job_est.val() == 'select') {
    job_est.addClass('hightlight');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much that worked very well is it wrong to use ajax in a html form like i have or it better to have it in a different page

Comment: Does not matter....you could use that. I think you have marked any other answer, that has bug

Comment: sorry what else has bugs

Comment: I am asking for the approved answer...that answer has bug

Comment: well your answer looks cleaner to me and seems to be work how i wanted thank you very much you have the approved answer

Comment: sorry one last question how would i get your part of the script to work on a checkbox

Comment: means you want checkboxes instead of selectbox ? 
Here is reference link http://www.chennaisunday.com/jscheckbox.html